# adding opacity to page

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I have a page with a background image and six tiles that are `links`, All of those are contained in a `<div id = "main">`. I also have a `side navbar` that pushes the content to the right when clicked on.
I want to also add some opacity to `#main`, but i am stuck.
Below is my javascript code for my `Side Navbar` where I am trying to change the backgroundColor, which I know is clearly wrong.  Is there a way to add opacity to an entire page?

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav(){
    navSize = document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;
    if (navSize === "400px") {
        return close();
    }
    return open();
}
function open() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "400px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
function close() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: you should post your HTML so we can see what you are actually working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not totally wrong, you have to use either `rgba()` or Hexadecimal notation of RGBA. You can read more about it on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba).
You can use it in your project as, 
`document.getElementById("main").style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";`
Above code will set `background` to `black` and `opacity` to `0.4`.

Or if you just want to toggle the Opacity then you have to set, `opacity` css property, as follows

`document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = 0.4`
Where `0.4` is opacity value. It ranges form 0 to 1, where 1 stands for fully visible and 0 means fully hidden. You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked, but I have two questions.  I thought an opacity of 1 means it's fully opaque, but when I set style.opacity =1, it's actually fully transparent.  Additionally, is there a way to define the color of the opacity?  With my current code document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = 0.4; the opacity color appears to be white, but ideally I would want a black opacity.  thanks!

Comment: @Dave, then you should `rgba()` to apply color with alpha channel aka opacity. Set `backgroun-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)`. `0.4` is opacity factor. Regarding setting opacity 1 gives you fully transparent, will check and let you know here asap.

Comment: Hey, my bad, I read the 0-1 opacity wrong.  You were right with your definition above.  So I tried the rgba method, but it doesn't work for me.  I used code document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = rgba(0,0,0,0.4); but it actually didn't recognize the opacity at all.

Comment: @Dave, `rgba()` is for setting color field. In your case, you have to set  `document.getElementById("footer").style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";`

Comment: I tried that at the very beginning, but it didn't work.  I don't think it worked because I have a background-image that takes up the entire page so a background color can't be seen.  It's almost like I want a translucent black overlay on top of my image.  In any case, it's not that important, but was just curious on how this could be done.  thanks!

Comment: There are many ways we can achieve that, but for that you need to provide more inputs like is background image is on div or entire page for start.

Comment: sorry, should have provided more details above.  basically I have a div id = "main" and beneath that I have <div class="background"> which is where my background image resides.  and finally below that div, I have <ul> and <li> tags for each of my tiles.